# How to run "Securepoint VPN client" as a "Microsoft Windows (WIN)" service?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

**PROBLEM**

For some reason the original OpenVPN software under Windows does not work for me. So I found an alternative from Securepoint that works for the first time. Unfortunately it does not have feature to run as a service, confirmed by vendor. You need to login to WIN gui first.

How can I run this VPN client automatically without WIN desktop login?

Comment: I do not understand who and why someone expressing negative to my description of the problem. If so, please express at least what bothers you. Some other my descriptions have been at first negative and for some time are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I consider that what you can manually it is also automated. So you can do that.

STEPS

1. Download "SRVSTART.EXE" application from http://rozanski.org.uk/software
2. Unpack and place it to path without spaces eg "c:\srvstart\"
3. Move "SecOpenVPN" from default path "Program Files" to own eg "c:\SecurepointSSLVPN\"
4. Run this program as an administrator "c:\srvstart\svc"

Install service steps

1. Action > press "i"
2. Enter the service name > write "Securepoint VPN client"
3. Enter display name > write "Securepoint VPN client"
4. Can the service interact with the desktop > press "n"
5. Enter start type > press "a"
6. Enter error control > press "i"
7. Enter binary path name > write "c:\SecurepointSSLVPN\Spvpncl.exe"
8. Start service using 'LocalSystem' account > press "n"
9. Enter service start name > write ".\{{user_name}}" --- desktop user_name under which is typically an executable
10. Enter service start password for user: write "{{password}}"
11. Re-enter password to confirm: write "{{password}}"
12. Does this service have dependencies > press "y"
13. Short name of dependent service > write "Securepoint VPN" and press "enter"
14. Are you sure you want to install service > press "y"
15. Press "x"

Set and run service steps

1. Open Run window with keys "WIN+R"
2. Write and open "services.msc"
3. Open properties "Securepoint VPN client"
4. On tab "General" set "Startup type: Automatic (Delayed Start)" and click "OK" --- this not affect your gui boot process
5. On tab "Log On" set password again --- for some reason os not accept svc password or svc not correctly save it
6. Open ["Command Line Interface (CLI)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)
7. Write and run "net start SecOpenVPN"

Now the application should be launched, so test some your connection.

Now test start app after reboot. In my environment it takes 1 ~ 3 minutes.

Comment: Why not use the standard OpenVPN package, it already includes a service, so you don't have to build your own.

Comment: Sure I know, but not work for me and Securepoint with no problem for the first time.